# spec.containers: Required value when using the Javascript client

Tags: kubernetes

Here is the Json I use as a Yaml

I used the same config to create a pod using kubectl and I had no problem.
I am providing the containers as a list, I don't see why it's not recognizing them.

```
{
    "metadata": {
      "name": "discord-bot-deployment",
      "labels": {
        "app": "discord-bot"
      }
    },
    "spec": {
      "replicas": 1,
      "selector": {
        "matchLabels": {
          "app": "discord-bot"
        }
      },
      "template": {
        "metadata": {
          "labels": {
            "app": "discord-bot"
          }
        },
        "spec": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "fakebot",
              "image": "botbotto/fakebot:fakebot",
              "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a valid JSON document. That means either (a) your problem is due this error or (b) what you've shown here is not actually what you're using in your code.

Comment: Remove the last comma on line `"imagePullPolicy": "Always",`
In JSON, there is no trailing comma after the last attribute in an object or the last item in a list.